# Convert a mySQL date to Javascript date

Tags: javascript, mysql, date

What would be the best way to convert a mysql date format date into a javascript Date object?

mySQL date format is 'YYYY-MM-DD' (ISO Format).

Comment: Are you having a specific problem? What have you tried so far? AAre you having a problem passing in the date to the javascript Date object?

Comment: Date.parse('2009-01-01');  does not work.  trying to find a way to get it converted.   the dates are coming via a json object from another company that returns the date in ISO format.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Given your clarification that you cannot change the format of the incoming date, you need something like this:

```
var dateParts = isoFormatDateString.split("-");
var jsDate = new Date(dateParts[0], dateParts[1] - 1, dateParts[2].substr(0,2));
```

Original response:

Is there a reason you can't get a timestamp instead of the date string? This would be done by something like:

```
 SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date) AS epoch_time FROM table;
```

Then get the epoch_time into JavaScript, and it's a simple matter of:

```
var myDate = new Date(epoch_time * 1000);
```

The multiplying by 1000 is because JavaScript takes milliseconds, and UNIX_TIMESTAMP gives seconds.

Comment: i have no access to change the way the data is returned to me.  I have an ISO formatted date, I need to transform it clientside.

Answer (score 39):

The shortest and fast method:

```
var mySQLDate = '2015-04-29 10:29:08';
new Date(Date.parse(mySQLDate.replace(/-/g, '/')));
```

Comment: Didn't work for me. I changed the replace statement to: replace(/[-]/g,'/')

Comment: date.replace(' ', 'T') -- Somewhat cleaner approach to convert into a valid MySql datetime value.

Answer (score 7):

`mySqlDate` is in the format "yyyy-mm-dd".

```
var javaDate = new Date(mySqlDate);
```

This line of code works fine for me.

Comment: This won't work for dates when the year is before 100AD.

Answer (score 3):

[UNIX timestamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) (milliseconds since the January 1, 1970) would be my preferred choice.

You can pass it around as an integer and use the JS [setTime()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_settime.asp) method to make a JS Date object from it.

Answer (score 3):

Now javascript can do this easily, no more moment.js or similar :) readable to humans, and the desired language.

```js
var MySQLDate = '2021-01-26 16:35:00';

var JavaScriptDate1 = new Date(MySQLDate).toLocaleDateString(
      'es-CO',
      {
        year: 'numeric',
        month: 'long',
        day: 'numeric',
        hour12: true,
        hour: '2-digit',
        minute: '2-digit'
      }
);
var JavaScriptDate2 = new Date(MySQLDate).toLocaleDateString(
      'ko-KR',
      {
        year: 'numeric',
        month: 'long',
        day: 'numeric',
        hour12: false,
        hour: '2-digit',
        minute: '2-digit'
      }
);

console.log(JavaScriptDate1);
console.log(JavaScriptDate2);
```

[See more info here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString)

Answer (score 2):

Stumbled on this looking to do exactly what the OP wanted, and used jhurshman answer so I +1'ed it, but it is incomplete as it will use `00:00:00 GMT-0500 (CDT)` for the time part as it is not passed to the date object (var jsDate).

In case anyone else is looking to create the full `Javascript` [date object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)

**ex:**

```
Sat Mar 29 2014 23:24:28 GMT-0500 (CDT)
```

Based on a MySQL [DATETIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html) format

**ex:**

```
'9999-12-31 23:59:59'.
```

You will want to use the following:

```
var dateParts = isoFormatDateString.split("-");
var jsDate = new Date(dateParts[0], dateParts[1] - 1, dateParts[2].substr(0, 2), dateParts[2].substr(3, 2), dateParts[2].substr(6, 2), dateParts[2].substr(9, 2));
```

It will return in the browsers current timezone as you are creating the date object, but I would do the timezone conversion on the backend in most cases.

Answer (score 2):

In AngularJS Way, Thanks to @Jonas Sciangula Street

```
.filter('toJSDate', function(){
        return function (dateString) {
            return new Date(Date.parse(dateString.replace('-','/','g')))
        };
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe something like?

```
[Y,M,D,h,m,s] = '2020-11-06 16:00:00'.split(/[- :]/)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split the date '-' as separator and use this constructor:

```
var d = new Date(Y, M - 1, D);
```

Comment: and how would I split it like that?

Comment: if ds = 'YYYY-MM-DD': ds.split('-')

Answer (score 0):

Building onto Jhurisman's answer. If you would want to set the date's time as well use the following:

```
var dateParts = mysqlDate;
var timeParts = dateParts[2].substr(3).split(":");

var jsDate = new Date(
                dateParts[0],
                dateParts[1] - 1,
                dateParts[2].substr(0,2),
                timeParts[0],
                timeParts[1],
                timeParts[2]
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the function to convert the time format.

````js
function sqlToJsDate(sqlDate){
    //sqlDate in SQL DATETIME format ("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.ms")
    var sqlDateArr1 = sqlDate.split("-");
    //format of sqlDateArr1[] = ['yyyy','mm','dd hh:mm:ms']
    var sYear = sqlDateArr1[0];
    var sMonth = (Number(sqlDateArr1[1]) - 1).toString();
    var sqlDateArr2 = sqlDateArr1[2].split(" ");
    //format of sqlDateArr2[] = ['dd', 'hh:mm:ss.ms']
    var sDay = sqlDateArr2[0];
    var sqlDateArr3 = sqlDateArr2[1].split(":");
    //format of sqlDateArr3[] = ['hh','mm','ss.ms']
    var sHour = sqlDateArr3[0];
    var sMinute = sqlDateArr3[1];
    var sqlDateArr4 = sqlDateArr3[2].split(".");
    //format of sqlDateArr4[] = ['ss','ms']
    var sSecond = sqlDateArr4[0];
    var sMillisecond = sqlDateArr4[1];
     
    return new Date(sYear,sMonth,sDay,sHour,sMinute,sSecond,sMillisecond);
}```

Reference:[DeepInTheCode][1]


  [1]: https://deepinthecode.com/2014/08/05/converting-a-sql-datetime-to-a-javascript-date/
````

Answer (score 0):

You can get MySQL date (yyyy-mm-dd) like this easy javascript

to get Date and time

```
var date = new Date();    
date.toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' ');
```

to get only date yyyy-mm-dd

```
var date = new Date();
date.toISOString().slice(0, 10).replace('T', ' ');
```

if you notice any change to date value add your time zone for example

```
var date = new Date(date+" GTM");  //for GMT time zone
```

Adapt it with your code

Answer (score -1):

**While JS does possess enough basic tools to do this, it's pretty simple to use**

```js
/**
 * Ashu, You first need to create a formatting function to pad numbers to two digits…
 **/
function twoDigits(d) {
    if(0 <= d && d < 10) return "0" + d.toString();
    if(-10 < d && d < 0) return "-0" + (-1*d).toString();
    return d.toString();
}


Date.prototype.toMysqlFormat = function() {
    return this.getUTCFullYear() + "-" + twoDigits(1 + this.getUTCMonth()) + "-" + twoDigits(this.getUTCDate()) + " " + twoDigits(this.getUTCHours()) + ":" + twoDigits(this.getUTCMinutes()) + ":" + twoDigits(this.getUTCSeconds());
};


var date = new Date();

document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = date;
document.getElementById("mysql_date").innerHTML = date.toMysqlFormat();
console.log(date.toMysqlFormat());
```

```html
Simple date:<div id="date"></div>

Converted Mysql Fromat: <div id="mysql_date"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function getJsDate(sqlDate){
    var returnValue;
    var timeString="00:00:00";
    try{
        var dateArray=sqlDate.trim().split(" ");
        var dateString=dateArray[0];
        if(dateArray.length>1){timeString=dateArray[1];}
        console.log(timeString);
        var yyyymmddArray=dateString.trim().split("-");
        var hhmmssArray=timeString.trim().split(":");
        returnValue = new Date(yyyymmddArray[0], (yyyymmddArray[1]-1), yyyymmddArray[2], hhmmssArray[0], hhmmssArray[1], hhmmssArray[2]);
    }catch(err){
        console.log("Error: "+ err.message);
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing information on how and why it solves the problem improves its long-term value.

Answer (score -1):

TypeScript with proper typing (no implicit string/int conversation):

```js
/**
 * @example
 * mysql_date_to_js_date("2019-12-31");
 */
export function mysql_date_to_js_date(mysql_date: string) {
    var parts = mysql_date.split("-");
    if (parts.length != 3) {
        return undefined;
    }
    var year = parseInt(parts[0]);
    var month = parseInt(parts[1]) - 1; // months indexes are zero based, e.g. 9 == Octobre
    var day = parseInt(parts[2]);
    return new Date(year, month, day);
}
```