# Appropriate JSON date format when sending from JSP to jQuery

Tags: json, jsp, datetime-format

As JSON format doesn't standardize dates subformat, this task is completely on a programmer, right?

When sending dates from PHP to Javascript and back I sent dates as a single integer in UNIX timestamp format (number of seconds since 01/01/1970).

On server:

```
$now = new DateTime('now');
$now->getTimestamp();
```

On client:

```
.success : function (data)
{
    var date = new Date(data * 1000);
}
```

What's the best format for sending dates from JSP? (I'm JSP and Java newbie).

1. Obviously, it has to be easy encoding/decoding using Java native classes as well as Javascript Date object.
2. There should not be any problems with overflowing (I'm afraid after 2038 my PHP code will break).

Regards,

Comment: Timestamps should be fine. What is your problem with that solution?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp new Date(milliseconds) //milliseconds since 1970/01/01 - so you've solved your own problem. I personally prefer to use yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii:ss format as it readable and different from UK and US formats.

Comment: @Waygood But how to parse/format from/to "yyyy-mm-dd" or "yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii:ss" in both Java and Javascript? I'd personally like to get rid of integers as well, since I'm not sure they always can keep such giant counts of milliseconds (what if 32 bit vs 64 bit implicit conversion somewhere or something like this...).

Comment: checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1765803/convert-a-mysql-date-to-javascript-date __AND__ http://www.roseindia.net/sql/sqldate/mysql-date-java.shtml

Answer (score 0):

> new Date(milliseconds) //milliseconds since 1970/01/01 - so you've solved your own problem. I personally prefer to use yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii:ss format as it readable and different from UK and US formats.