# AngularJS | date filter does not seem to be changing the way my date displays at all

Tags: angularjs

I have the following in my HTML:

```
{{ row.createdDate }}
```

The date for this is coming from JSON and looks like this: "createdDate=13-08-2013 03:02"

This creates a date: "13-08-2013 03:27"

I changed this to:

```
{{ row.createdDate | date:'MM/dd/yy HH:mm' }}
```

Still it creates the same date: "13-08-2013 03:27"

It seems that the date filter is not doing anything for me. Is the problem that the date filter requires the date to be in a specific format and if so what format should my date be in. Here is the format that I am currently using with MS Web API:

```
json.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add( 
    new IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm" });
```

Comment: If you refer to the angularJS documentation, the date filter will work only if it recognize a date, or if you provide a timestamp. Have you tried with a timestamp ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be someting to do with the datatype of `row.createdDate`. I think you need to use `date` type variable expression, as:

First, in controller, you can add one more function to get date type variable from your string type variable, as

```
$scope.GetCreateDate = function () {
            return new Date(row.createdDate);
        };
```

and then use that date type variable in your binding expression, as:

```
{{ row.GetCreateDate | date:'MM/dd/yy HH:mm' }}
```

Answer (score 2):

I took Sanjeev's answer combined it with [Convert a mySQL date to Javascript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1765803/convert-a-mysql-date-to-javascript-date) and made a more generic version of it.

Put this in your controller:

```
  $scope.toJsDate = function(str){
    if(!str)return null;
    var t = str.split(/[- :]/);
    var d = new Date(t[0], t[1]-1, t[2], t[3], t[4], t[5]);
    return d;
  }
```

And put this in your HTML:

```
{{toJsDate('2013-09-19 02:23:51') | date:'MM/dd/yyyy @ h:mma'}}
```

Another option is to use a filter like: [AngularJS: How to format ISO8601 date format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16451851/angularjs-how-to-format-iso8601-date-format?rq=1)