# Converting the sql date to MM/DD/YYYY

Tags: javascript, node-mssql

the timestamp I receive from Api is something like 2018-02-24T00:00:00 , but what I need is MM/DD/YYYY so.. it would look something like 02/24/2018, I receive timestamp from mssql and want to convert it using javascript

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a mySQL date to Javascript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1765803/convert-a-mysql-date-to-javascript-date)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take some time to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You should first research for your own, tell what you've tried to achieve the goal and add a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your question if possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT FORMAT (timestamp, 'MM/dd/yyyy') as date
GO
```

or as US culture

```
SELECT FORMAT (timestamp, 'd', 'en-us') as date
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```js
function getFormattedDate(date) {
    let year = date.getFullYear();
    let month = (1 + date.getMonth()).toString().padStart(2, '0');
    let day = date.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0');
  
    return `${month}/${day}/${year}`;
}
```

```js
function getFormattedDate(date) {
    let year = date.getFullYear();
    let month = (1 + date.getMonth()).toString().padStart(2, '0');
    let day = date.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0');
  
    return `${month}/${day}/${year}`;
}

console.log(getFormattedDate(new Date('2018-02-24T00:00:00')))
```